# Proper place to set fragment tag

Tags: android, android-fragments

When I want to open a new fragment I call this method (which normally works):

```
openFragment(getActivity(), R.id.fragment_holder_id, MyFragment.newInstance());
```

Problem I'm dealing with is fragment tag which is always returning null, before and after commmit.

```
public static void openFragment(Activity activity, int fragmentHolderId, Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = activity.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    System.out.println("Tag Before Commit: " + fragment.getTag()); // null
    fragmentTransaction.replace(fragmentHolderId, fragment, fragment.getTag());
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
    System.out.println("Tag After Commit: " + fragment.getTag()); // null
}
```

Where is proper place to set fragment tag ?

Comment: You should set the tag when you create a Fragment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use of **TAG** is to identify fragment uniquely from pool of fragment in transaction .

So while **replace()** set **TAG**

From which you can access fragment later by following code

```
Fragment fragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("YOUR_TAG");
```